# mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_REQUEST) for all variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm Using Mysqli for the first time .

In mysql i have used this .

```
$escapedGet = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST);
extarct($escapedGet ).
```

now i have tried a lot for `mysqli_real_escape_string` with `mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_REQUEST)`

it says second parameter should be string , i tried passing it with string with a loop , but can't make it work , can anyone help please .

Thanks in advance

Comment: i'm using mysqli :) for the first time . and need help with mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_REQUEST) for all $_request values .

Comment: Have a look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). It's really much better that using `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: You shouldn't arbitrarily escape every input variable. Use `filter_input_array()` to removed unwanted variables (it's far more intelligent than escaping stuff), then escape those variables that need it at the point you're building your query.

Answer (score 2):

I do that this way:

```
function sanitize($value){
    global $mysqli;
    return $mysqli->real_escape_string($value);
}

if($_POST){$_POST = array_map('sanitize', $_POST);}
if($_GET){$_GET = array_map('sanitize', $_GET);}
if($_COOKIE){$_COOKIE = array_map('sanitize', $_COOKIE);}
if($_REQUEST){$_REQUEST = array_map('sanitize', $_REQUEST);}
```

Comment: one more problem , now when i'm sending array on form submit . it send blank value . and array count returns zero .

Comment: It seems like a new issue to post as a question with detailed information :)